# Vim spell check does not work with text file

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I tried spell check for text file by adding this to my vimrc

```
augroup set_spell
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType text :setlocal spell spelllang=en_us
augroup END
nnoremap <F10> :setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us<CR>
```

And it did not work  
I tried `:set spell` and nothing happened  
For some reasons, when I ran `:source $MYVIMRC` (still in that window), it worked. Though I can add sourcing command to my vimrc but I don't like the glitchy feeling of it.  
What am I supposed to do?

Edit: I have found the solution

It's the problem with this vim rainbow plugin
https://github.com/frazrepo/vim-rainbow
So I uninstall that one and install this instead https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow

Comment: What does not working mean?

Answer (score 4):

Open the file and immediately do a `:set ft?` and `:set spell?`. Make sure they return `text` and `spell` respectively. If `text` is not returned, then the filetype is not being detected. If `text` is returned but `spell` is not, then the autocommand is not working.

Additionally, you should wrap autcommands in an `augroup`. See `:h autocmd-groups`. It might look like this:

```
augroup set_spell
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType text setlocal spell
augroup END
```

Because this is a FileType autocommand, you are probably better off skipping the augroup and autocommands altogether and just putting the line `setlocal spell` in an ftplugin file. It would normally go in `~/vim/ftplugin/text.vim`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I run both command and they return 'text' and 'spell'. The problem is that spell check is not working. I think I did not give a clear description of my situation here. I've updated it. If you have any idea, please let me know

Comment: You ran both of those while spell checking was not working, right? You didn't source your vimrc first? Try doing `:verbose set spell?` and see what it says; it tells you the last thing which turned on spell. And is there anything else in your vimrc?

Comment: Here: "Last set from ~/.config/nvim/init.vim". And I add my vimrc spell check section to my question

Comment: You may want to check for differences between vim and neovim regarding the `spell` option. Beyond that I have no more information for you.

Comment: I also have a problem.  vim's spell will check some of my .tex files, but not others.  On some of them the filetype is identified "tex" and doesn't work.  on others the filetype is identified as "plaintex" and it does work, just the way I want it.  I can't figure out what the triggers are.  In both cases most of the file is text, with little markup syntax.

Comment: and my fix is manually setting the filetype...  :set filetype=plaintex

Comment: @user12711 if you look at vim's help with `:h ft-tex-plugin` it explains how it sets `ft` as tex, plaintex, or latex. If you always use plaintex, you can put `let g:tex_flavor = "plain"` in your .vimrc. There's more info and options if you look at `:h tex` as well.

Comment: That works, but my files are actually .tex rather than plaintex files.  And they are super simple files with very little markup and lots of regular text paragraphs, one file per chapter.  So, I'm guessing my colorscheme syntax file for    .vim/syntax/tex.vim    is expecting to see a "LaTeX Preamble" on top of every chapter.tex file, which is so common in documents.tex files.  The tex.vim syntax file has much better highlighting than the plaintex.vim syntax file, but have to use "plaintex" vim spell to work.  There should be a simple    /.vim/after/sytnax/tex.vim    to reset the problem group?

Comment: @doopNudles that works!  I'm still trying to figure out how to modify my 
    tex.vim    
 syntax file, so that it will spell check properly.  It has a better colorscheme.  The problem highlight group is named "Normal"  How do I tell vim spell to check the "Normal" group.  It's regular paragraphs of text suitable for spell checking, but vim spell won't check it, even when on.  So I change to plaintex filetype and vim spell works, but the highlighting from plaintex.vim isn't as good as tex.vim.  I'm guessing there's a simple fix that I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

As a more general solution: Sometimes theme plugins overwrite SpellBad highlight group(It's one those gui vs terminal problems). Even though spell check works it just doesn't highlight. Without deleting your theme you can just add more style to the SpellBad highlight group as you wish:

Simply add this to your .vimrc:

```
"underline spell errors in terminals
hi SpellBad cterm=underline
```

or any other style really:

```
hi SpellBad ctermfg=Cyan cterm=bold
```

Be warned, these do not overwrite all existing styles. To truly overwriting it you may need to use `hi clear SpellBad` first.

See `:h highlight` for all the details. For the other Spell groups see `:h hl-SpellBad`.